# Why is Firefox 4 ignoring my mouse scrollwheel input?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, mouse-wheel, scroll-wheel

This is getting on my nerves - for some reason Firefox 4 is ignoring my mouse scrollwheel input. In other words, rolling the scrollwheel does nothing in Firefox 4.

It works fine in just about every other application. Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Enabling/Disabling Smooth Scroll & Autoscroll ( and the various permutations of the two settings) seem to have no effect.

Comment: Ridiculous. I just typed in the question and the scroll wheel started working :\

Comment: I think it might have to do with where the focus is within the window.  Flash animations are bad for stealing focus.

Comment: @aking1012 - agree with the focus, but I don't have Flash installed (yet). This is a mint fresh Windows desktop, FF just installed, no addons as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, Lenovo's mouse drivers and their mouse suite for "extended" features are really crappy. I cannot uninstall them, but can unload them & doing so fixed this.

Comment: Actually, turns out you pretty much CAN uninstall the mouse drivers, which will both solve the problem and not cause any long-running issues. (Uninstalled `Lenovo Mouse Suite` from under `Programs and Features` and the scroll-wheel seems to be working just fine now)

Answer (score 2):

I have this happen from time to time, but clicking on another window and then back to Firefox fixes it.  I believe it is a focus issue as aking1012 mentions.

[Here](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Cannot%20scroll%20with%20mouse%20wheel%20or%20touchpad) are some settings related to the scroll wheel which you could try.  I also read elsewhere that the `general.autoScroll` setting in `about:config` should be set to true.  Finally, based on [this page](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/804566), you could try setting `mousewheel.emulate_at_wm_scroll` to true.

Comment: Interesting that the system reported by the user in the Mozilla Link that you referenced happens to be the same one that I use.